# mongoose $or with mixed string and _id (ObjectId) not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a method to fetch a "page" from the document base where the query matches `_id` *or* `permalink`.

The below code example returns a mongoose error:

> 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "hello-world" at path "_id" for model "pages"'

Now, obviously the query isn't an ObjectId if the case is 'hello-world' or any other string permalink. So how do I go about using $or in this case, or is there a smarter way to go about it?

```
/**
 * Describes methods to create, retrieve, update, and delete pages
 * @returns void
 */
function Pages() {
    this.pages = require('../models/pages')
    this.users = require('../models/users')
    require('mongoose').connect(require('../../config/database/mongodb').url)
}

/**
 * Retrieve a page by permalink or id
 * @param {string} pageQuery - id or permalink
 * @callback {function} cFunction
 */
Pages.prototype.getOne = function(pageQuery, cFunction) {
    this.pages.findOne({$or: [{ 'permalink': pageQuery }, { '_id': pageQuery }] })
    .populate('author', 'email')
    .select('title permalink body author')
    .exec(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            cFunction(error)
            return
        }
        cFunction(result)
    })
}
```

**Pages model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,
    pages = new Schema({
        title: { type: String },
        permalink: { type: String, unique: true },
        body: { type: String },
        author: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
        createdAt: { type: Date },
        revisedAt: { type: Date }
    })
    .index({
        title: 'text',
        permalink: 'text',
        body: 'text'
    })
    module.exports = mongoose.model('pages', pages)
```

**Users model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,
    users = new Schema({
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        username: { type: String, unique: true },
        password: { type: String },
        createdAt: { type: Date }
    })
    .index({
        email: 'text',
        username: 'text'
    })
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users)
```

Comment: It looks like the current value passed in as `pageQuery` is `"hello-world"`. I think you were debugging something and forgot to remove a variable declaration somewhere. Hence the error.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've added models for both pages and users in my question. Yes, I am querying on 'hello-world' in the test, but that's the whole point. I wan to be able to retrieve a page from the document base where id OR permalink matches the query, which can be an id OR a permalink.

Comment: Yeah I retracted that since you clearly are supplying that string as input to this function. *"Search your code, you know this to be true"*

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I _am_ providing that string (hello-world) as the method argument, which is exactly what I want to be able to... I am not sure what you mean tbh...

Comment: I mean it's the cause of the error. Mongoose is trying to "cast" like this `ObjectId("hello-world")` because it's looking in `_id` which has a default `Schema.types.ObjectId`. If you intend to match `_id` values in the database that are actually "strings" `_id: "hello-world"` then you need to define `_id` in your schema as a "string" instead. But I don't think you really want that and this is just a silly mistake.\

Comment: This is your code `{ '_id': pageQuery }` so if pageQuery is being fed `"hello-world"` then of course it is going to error.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, that's what the error basically says, and why I commented in my question, that I do know that the string "hello-world" is not, in fact, an ObjectId, and also why I ask if there is any other way around achieving what I want.

Comment: If you don't get by now I can't see how you are ever going to. Take a step back and think about what you are asking things to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if you run `new ObjectId(pageQuery)` and it's not a valid ObjectId, it will throw an error telling you that (i.e. Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.)

In saying that, I would just use a try/catch block at the beginning of `Pages.prototype.getOne` to try and cast a pageQueryOid variable, and if you get to the catch block you know it's because pageQuery is not a valid ObjectId.

Using this method you no longer need an $or filter, but can just build your exact filter based on if pageQuery is a valid ObjectId. The following is just an example of what this might look like, but you can update it to meet your needs:

```
Pages.prototype.getOne = function(pageQuery, cFunction) {
    var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId
    var pageQueryOid
    try {
      pageQueryOid = new ObjectId(pageQuery)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("pageQuery is not a valid ObjectId...")
    }

    var filter
    if (pageQueryOid) {
      filter = { '_id': pageQueryOid }
    } else {
      filter = { 'permalink': pageQuery }
    }

    this.pages.findOne(filter)
    .populate('author', 'email')
    .select('title permalink body author')
    .exec(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            cFunction(error)
            return
        }
        cFunction(result)
    })
}
```